# Design is not proper of ngx-material-timepicker when set minutesGap was 1

Tags: css, angular, typescript

[image]

Here is my HTML code

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>StartTime</mat-label>
  <input matInput readonly [ngxTimepicker]="timeStart" [formControlName]="'startTime'" [format]="24" />
  <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle [for]="timeStart">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="mat_solid:access_time" ngxMaterialTimepickerToggleIcon></mat-icon>
  </ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
  <ngx-material-timepicker #timeStart [minutesGap]="1" disabled="false"></ngx-material-timepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this using add below css

I have added **'one-minute-gap'** this custom class for this time picker and apply css on that so other time picker will not affect,

**component.html** file

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>StartTime</mat-label>
  <input matInput readonly [ngxTimepicker]="timeStart" [formControlName]="'startTime'" [format]="24" />
  <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle [for]="timeStart">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="mat_solid:access_time" ngxMaterialTimepickerToggleIcon></mat-icon>
  </ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
  <ngx-material-timepicker #timeStart [minutesGap]="1" disabled="false" [timepickerClass]="'one-minute-gap'"></ngx-material-timepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**component.scss** file

```
::ng-deep .one-minute-gap {
    width: auto !important;
    ngx-material-timepicker-dial{
        .timepicker-dial{
            .timepicker-dial__container{
                justify-content: center !important;
            }
        }
    }
    ngx-material-timepicker-minutes-face {
        ngx-material-timepicker-face {
            .clock-face {
                width: 370px !important;
                height: 370px !important;
                padding: 5px !important;

                .clock-face__container {
                    .clock-face__number--outer {
                        height: calc(400px / 2 - 20px) !important;
                        span {
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's look like below

[image]

Comment: You can use production ready solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dhutaryan/ngx-mat-timepicker